# How to combine data from two sequences of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, sequences

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [{'tag':'XXX', 'key1':'a'}, {'tag':'YYY', 'key1':'a'}]

list2 = [{'tag':'XXX', 'key1':'c'}, {'tag':'ZZZ', 'key1':'d'}]
```

I need to build a new list:

```
 comblist = [{'tag':'XXX', 'key1':'a'}, {'tag':'YYY', 'key1':'a'}, {'tag':'ZZZ', 'key1':'d'}]
```

I need to add elements from list2 to list1, but only that for which value of key 'tag' isn't present in values of key 'tag' in list1.

Comment: I doubt a list of dictionaries is the best data structure here; if you had an outer dictionary mapping tags to inner dictionaries this would be much easier.

Comment: Real data come from csv.DictReader object. Next they are deduplicated. Output structure is list of dictionaries. Can You give me a simple example of your's conception?  My english isnt good and i don't know exacly what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first create a set of tag values from list1 and then use a comprehension to extend list1 by dictionaries in list 2 which have new tags:

```
>>> list1 = [{'tag':'XXX', 'key1':'a'}, {'tag':'YYY', 'key1':'a'}]
>>> list2 = [{'tag':'XXX', 'key1':'c'}, {'tag':'ZZZ', 'key1':'d'}]
>>> tags = set(d['tag'] for d in list1)
>>> list1.extend(d for d in list2 if not d['tag'] in tags)
>>> list1
[{'key1': 'a', 'tag': 'XXX'}, {'key1': 'a', 'tag': 'YYY'}, {'key1': 'd', 'tag': 'ZZZ'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simple using update method of dictionary:

```
dict1 = dict((x['tag'], x['key1']) for x in list1)
dict2 = dict((x['tag'], x['key1']) for x in list2)

result = dict2.copy()
result.update(dict1)

result = [{'tag': key, 'key1': value} for key, value in result.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

So i built function:

```
def add(seq1, seq2, key=None):
seen = set()
#add values from seq1 for selected key (or keys) to seen.
for item in seq1:
    seen.add(key(item))
# Check if value(s) for selected key(s) is in seen.   
for item in seq2:
    # if statemant added for support two types of sequences lists end dicts
    val = item if key is None else key(item)
    if val not in seen:
        # Add selected element from seq2 to seq1 and value of key to seen
        seq1.append(item)
        seen.add(val)
return seq1
```

and call it:

```
comblist = list(add(list1, list2, key=lambda d: d['tag']))
```

It work good.
Function is suitable for different kinds of data structures and properties.
I'm not pro and i'm curious. Is there any easier or faster way?
My lists consist of over 1500 dictionaries, and each dict has 15 key, value pairs.

Comment: I think this *is* an answer (albeit slow) to the question as asked. If the real question is - how do I make this faster or more concise, then the entirety of the answer should probably be the question.